# Getting 'Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' when retrieving items from JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq

When having the following code

```
var TermSource =
token.Value<JArray>("annotations")
     .Values<string>("Term Source")
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

I am able to get results for the following JSON block

```
"annotations": [
  {
     "Preferred Term": "Text1"
  },
  {
     "Term Source": "Text2"
  }
],
```

However, when running the following line

```
var country_code_iso3166_alpha2 =
    token.Value<JArray>("datatype_properties")
         .Values<string>("country_code_iso3166_alpha2")
         .FirstOrDefault();
```

for the following JSON block

```
"datatype_properties": {
  "country_name_iso3166_short": [
    "Text Text"
  ],
  "country_code_iso3166_alpha2": [
    "txt1"
  ],
  "country_code_iso3166_alpha3": [
    "txt2"
  ],
  "country_code_un_numeric3": [
    "10"
  ]
```

I get the following error

*'Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken'*

How I should fix the LINQ statement to retrieve the value for the 'country_code_iso3166_alpha2' data

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're trying to access `datatype_properties` as if it's an array. It's not - it's another object with a property `country_code_iso3166_alpha3` which has an array value.

You can call the `Value` method with a `JObject` type argument to get the object, then `Value` again with a `JArray` type argument to get the array. Here's a short but complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"{
  'datatype_properties': {
    'country_name_iso3166_short': [
      'Text Text'
    ]
  }
}".Replace("'", "\"");
        JObject parent = JObject.Parse(json);
        string countryName = parent["datatype_properties"]
            .Value<JArray>("country_name_iso3166_short")
            .Values<string>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(countryName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, sir!